# Passing arguments to Ruby file call

Tags: ruby

I have a program `test.rb` I want to be able to pass arguments to the program, much like you can do in the C language. For example:

```
ruby test.rb  param1
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Lots of answers are available in SO for this,search it and use it. Don't post the same questions please.

Comment: I am sorry for that .I am a freshman in Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use ARGV

The special [ARGV](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#ARGV) array contains the arguments passed to a Ruby script. For example:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts ARGV.inspect' param1
["param1"]
```

See also [ARGF#argv](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/ARGF.html#method-i-argv).

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has a lib included that handles command line option: Options Parser

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html

A simple example ruby program:

```
require 'optparse'

# create hash to hold program options
program_options = {}

# Parse the options passed into via command line
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options]"

  opts.on("-v", "--[no-]verbose", "Run verbosely") do |v|
    options[:verbose] = v
  end
end.parse!

# Run Program Code
# ...
# your program will have access to the program_options hash
```

then run the program with `ruby example.rb -v`

`opts.on` has many options for detecting long (i.e., --verbose) and short (i.e., -v) switches,  as well as accepting input and optional switches

Comment: Don't put only the doc link. Give some example codes also,so that future users can use it directly from here.

Comment: yes , a easy example codes will be appreciated.